# Wget schedule sending mail if response time > 5 secs

Tags: wget, scheduled

I'm using a script called Responser which sends email when any of the my sites are down/slow. I just wanted to check if it's sending the mail only if the sites are really down or slow(as I checked it accessing as soon I got the error mails and sites was fine). I thought of using `wget` as it shows the speed and response time and I want to schedule it to compare it with my responser script whether both sends the mail at the same time saying error.

I've postfix installed and I could send mails using `mail` command to any e-mail id from the terminal. I want the output of `wget http://www.mysite.com` to be mailed with the condition if response time is greater than 5 seconds. Then I can schedule it to run at every 5 mins. I saw many having good programming skills here and hope someone could help me.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The script you want is something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# by desgua to test server down
# 
# This script is supposed to be named ".ping.time.sh" and
# to be put at ~/
# to test what happens when server is down: 
# change www.mysite.com for www.serverdown.com  
# 
# As asked, I supposed you have a script to send mail and named
# ~/.script.to.send.mail.sh 
# 
sleep 300          # as asked, to run at every 5 minutes
pingtime=$(ping -w 5 www.mysite.com | grep ttl)

echo $pingtime

if [ $pingtime = ] ; then 
   echo 'down' ; ~/.script.to.send.mail.sh ; else
   echo 'up' ; ~/.ping.time.sh
fi
```

ps. At your script to send the email, put something to run again the script I made after the mail has been sent

Comment: The domain names are globally registered but I couldn't ping to them

Comment: `PING www.mysite.com (204.200.xx.xx) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
---www.mysite.com ping statistics ---`

Comment: No, it's just an output of `ping www.mysite.com`

Comment: I have firewall settings on my server and so it won't ping

Comment: You sure know how to configure it to allow ping, right? You don't want to allow ping or you need help to configure it?